# reading from ComboBox

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox

how can i read the text of a selected value of a comboBox in windows aplication(borland C++) for example:
i have combobox which contains 2 values (sum and mult) i want to see if it is sum i have to add the numbers and if it mult i have to multiplicate the numbers so how can i read the value of combobox in this case.

Comment: You should really edit your existing question to make it clearer, rather than ask another question which is almost identical...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805027/how-to-read-combobox-in-c

Comment: If the answers you got to your previous question didn't help you, it's because your question was poorly written. Instead of posting an entirely new question, please go back and *edit* your original question to include additional details and information. You can also leave comments for the people who tried to answer your question asking for further clarification.

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5805292/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.  I've merged the two questions together, so please, everybody, don't close as dupe.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I never work with c++ with winapplication but i tried it with the c# and hopefully that you want the desired output as i got through your question if it is not right then you should edit your question.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        if (comboBox1.Text == "ADD")  
        {  
            int a = 12, b = 13, c;  
            c = a + b;  
            MessageBox.Show("Result of adding= " + c);  
        }  
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Multiple")  
        {  
             int x = 3, y = 5, z;  
            z = x * y;  
            MessageBox.Show("Result of multiplication= " + z);  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: downvoter can you explain why you give me minus point as i have mentioned that the question is not much clear but i tried to help as i got the question.

Comment: Probably because you didn't answer the question, and didn't care enough to even format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Windows, you can use the following messages:

`WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` and `WM_GETTEXT`.

Firstly, get the length of the selected text, then allocate your buffer to ensure it's large enough, then retrieve the actual text. Easy.

Example:

```
const UINT length = ::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
LPTSTR pszText = new TCHAR[length + 1];
::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, length + 1, pszText);

// pszText will now contain the text you want, do what you want with it

delete[] pszText; // Remember to delete else you will leak.
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

In your window procedure use the `WM_COMMAND` message and then check for a `CBN_SELCHANGE` notification. Then use `WM_GETTEXT` along with `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` to receive the selected text like Mark Ingram says. Or you can also use `CB_GETCURSEL` to receive the identifier of the selected item.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam)) {
                case IDC_COMBO:
                    if (HIWORD(wParam) == CBN_SELCHANGE) {
                        HWND hCtl = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_COMBO);//Get handle for HMENU item
                        if (SendMessage(hCtl, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0) == compareValue) {
                            //...
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            break;
        //...
    }
}
```